# SPARQL: Combine two select statements that each have a GROUP BY clause

Tags: group-by, sparql

Hello I am trying to find the total number of municipalities a region has along with the name of each region and the total number of municipalities a regional unit has along with the name of the regional unit. A **region** consists of **regional units** and a regional unit consists of **municipalities**. Below is my query that unfortunately returns wrong results. What I am basically trying to do is group by region and get the name and the total municipalities of each region and group by regional unit and take the name and the total municipalities of each unit. Any suggestions to the right direction would be appreciated. Cheers!:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema 
PREFIX strdf: <http://strdf.di.uoa.gr/ontology
PREFIX gag: <http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/ontology/> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT ?region ?municipality_region ?unit ?municipality_unit
WHERE
{
 { SELECT ?region (COUNT(?municipality) AS ?municipality_region)
 {?m rdf:type gag:Δήμος .
  ?m gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?municipality .
  ?m gag:ανήκει_σε ?reg_un .
  ?reg_un gag:ανήκει_σε ?reg .
  ?reg gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?region .
 }GROUP BY ?region}
{ SELECT ?unit (COUNT(?municipality_un) AS ?municipality_unit) 
 { ?m rdf:type gag:Δήμος .
   ?m gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?municipality_un .
   ?m gag:ανήκει_σε ?reg_un .
   ?reg_un gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?unit .
  } GROUP BY ?unit}
};
```

Below I am giving a mapping of properties in english:

```
Δήμος = municipality
έχει_επίσημο_όνομα = has name
ανήκει_σε = belongs to
```

And here is the ontology I am working with:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d3zW03vQCNp0MARUSo6PorwPV4VW0KlT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what does not work? I mean I don't get what the expected result is, both subqueries resp. their result are obviously not connected, neither syntactically (nor variable) nor semantically (one is result for region, their other for regional units) - if you want to connect both subqueries, you should do this in the outer query, i.e. reuse the triple patterns from your second query that connect region with regional unit.

Comment: and currently you simply get the cartesian product of both resultsets, i.e. `{a,b} x {c,d} = {(a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d)}`

Comment: @UninformedUser Ooh ok I understand. I actually want them to be connected so I will try to do that. Thanks.

Comment: it should be just `?reg_un gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?unit . ?unit gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?region .` in the outer query to connect region with unit from your subqueries, does it work?